# What type of potentiometer to use for 240v AC power application?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply

I'm working on my first Raspberry Pi project which is to change the brightness of standard household light bulbs.

I have my Raspberry Pi and relay switches which together let me control when the power will come on. Now I want to use Raspberry Pi to control the brightness of the light.

What component do I need to use for that? also any pointer to tutorials are appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are experienced, a 240V project is a dangerous choice for a first project. I think you'd need to isolate mains from low voltage circuits (e.g. opto-isolator); maintain large clearance/creepage distance between high and low-voltage parts; pay careful attention to earthing and insulation, strain-relief, fuses etc.

Comment: You don't want to use a potentiometer, certainly!

Comment: I think you should look for a module like this one: http://www.inmojo.com/store/inmojo-market/item/digital-ac-dimmer-module/ My gut feeling says the price on this particular module is pretty steep, but I let the shopping to yourself. Please be very careful when it comes to mains power, as @RedGrittyBrick already explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with normal incandescent lights (or compatible CFLs), the optimal way to dim them is not with a potentiometer but with a circuit called a triac dimmer. The triac blocks an adjustable portion of the AC waveform from reaching the light, reducing it's average power and subequent light output.

Google has tons of information on the topic.